# DynamoDB retrieving referenced value in table

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a table where by running a single query `select * where pk = A#1` returns a list of the names of A#1, B#1, B#2. Is there some kind of way to retrieve the values of (B#1, B#1) and (B#2, B#2) with it? or do I have to simply duplicate the name data into the reference items and update them whenever the original is updated?

| pk | sk | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A#1 | A#1 | name1 |
| A#1 | B#1 |  |
| B#1 | B#1 | name2 |
| A#1 | B#2 |  |
| B#2 | B#2 | name3 |

Wanted behaviour
`select * from table where pk = A#1 join on sk names`
returns

```
A#1 A#1 name1
A#1 B#1 name2
A#1 B#2 name3
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand your question. Can you give an example of the data you wish to retrieve. Your example query will return 3 rows of data from the table. Which rows do you want it to return?

Comment: Added the wanted behavior

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you would need to use a `FilterCondition` to return only the items which `name` `exists()`. You can see more about filter conditions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression

You could add name to the SK of the rows which contain them, that would mean you could retrieve them more efficiently:

```
A#1 NAME#A#1    name1
A#1 B#1 
B#1 NAME#B#1    name2
A#1 B#2 
B#2 NAME#B#2    name3
```

`select * from table where pk = A#1 and sk begins_with("NAME")`

Comment: But that query would only return `A#1 NAME#A#1 name1` no?

Comment: Yes, but you expect to be returned `A#1 B#1 name2` and that item does not belong in the table which you shared.